# why is hot-reloading is not working on Gridsome

Tags: vue.js, webpack, windows-subsystem-for-linux, hot-reload, gridsome

After making updates on default.vue the browser reports`"[HMR] Waiting for update signal from WDS..."` indefinitely. Reloading the browser does not help. Eventually I have to restart gridsome to see the changes.

### Steps to reproduce

- installed Gridsome and set up a new project using the CLI
- run `gridsome develop`
- check http://localhost:8080/ ...it works.
- check http://localhost:8080/___explore ...works
- tested a query .. works.
- modified gridsome.config.js to add
  `siteDescription: 'this is a test gridsome site'`
- restarted gridsome and verified siteDescription on `___explore` and on `localhost`
- added `<p>Description: {{ $static.metadata.siteDescription }}</p> before <slot\>` on
  `layouts\Default.vue`
- hit 'save' and expected hot-reload to update page

### Expected result

- Expected to see updates on localhost upon save.
- Browser stuck on "Waiting for update signal from WDS..."

### Actual result

No change, I had to restart the server to see the changes

### Environment

System:

```
OS: Windows WSL - Linux 5.10 Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS (Focal Fossa)
CPU: (12) x64 AMD Ryzen 5 3600 6-Core Processor
```

Binaries:

```
Node: 16.15.1 - ~/.nvm/versions/node/v16.15.1/bin/node
Yarn: 1.22.19 - ~/.nvm/versions/node/v16.15.1/bin/yarn
npm: 8.11.0 - ~/.nvm/versions/node/v16.15.1/bin/npm
```

npmGlobalPackages:

```
@gridsome/cli: 0.3.4
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out this was an issue with WSL and Webpack not working when the repo is outside the WSL file system. It kind'a makes sense that Webpack could not monitor a "remote" machine which is what WSL is. But WSL should have made this seamless by now.

So you could move your files to the ubuntu folder https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/whats-new-for-wsl-in-windows-10-version-1903/

Or like me, just switch to all-windows development.